# Unable to send mail without using intent chooser in android

Tags: android, sendmail

```js
05-31 12:43:53.615: E/dalvikvm(15521): Could not find class 'com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail$1', referenced from method com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail.doInBackground
05-31 12:43:53.615: E/dalvikvm(15521): Could not find class 'com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail$1', referenced from method com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail.doInBackground
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/doInBackground(15521): ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521): Process: com.example.demosendmail, PID: 15521
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail$1
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:121)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-31 12:43:53.655: E/AndroidRuntime(15521):  ... 4 more
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42ae5b08 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:460)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity$sendMail.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:105)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at com.example.demosendmail.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:69)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-31 12:43:54.260: E/WindowManager(15521):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i am trying to make a page on which there are three fields and a button and on button i m trying to send the mail but i am unable to do this my code is and when i click on button it show the error and my application stops

```html
package com.example.demosendmail;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;





public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 private EditText editName;
 private EditText editContact;
 private EditText editIssue;
 private Button btnSend;
    String username="aaa.singh33@gmail.com";
    String password="";// my password
 String reciepint="anurag290488@gmail.com";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  initView();
 }

 private void initView() {
  editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
  editContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_contact);
  editIssue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_issue);
  btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
  btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  
  int connection=hasConnection();   
  if(connection==1){
   new sendMail().execute();
  }
  else{
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No network available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } 
 }
 
 public  int hasConnection() {
  int flag=0;
  ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
   flag=1;
  }

  if(flag==0)
  {
   return 0;
  }
  else 
  {
   return 1;
  }
}
 
 private class sendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  private ProgressDialog pDialog;

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();

   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Publishing recipe.");
   pDialog.setCancelable(false);
   pDialog.show();

  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
   Log.e("doInBackground","ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc");

   Properties props = new Properties();
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
   props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");


   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance (props, new javax.mail.Authenticator () {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication () {
     return new PasswordAuthentication (username,password);
    }
   });
   
  
   try {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(reciepint));
    message.setSubject("Composed Recipe");

    String msg="Name = "+editName.getText().toString()+"    "+
    "Contact No = "+editContact.getText().toString()+"    "+
    "Issue= "+editIssue.getText().toString();
      

//    if(!ConstantsValues.COMPOSE_RECIPE_PICTURE_PATH.equals("empty")){     
//     Log.e("send mail","with attachment");  
//
//     BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();  
//     messageBodyPart1.setText(msg);   
//     MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
//     Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
//     messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
//     String file = ConstantsValues.COMPOSE_RECIPE_PICTURE_PATH;
//     String fileName = "image";
//     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
//     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
//     messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
//     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);
//     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
//     message.setContent(multipart);
//    }
//    else{   
//     Log.e("send mail","without attachment");
     message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
//    }

    Transport.send(message);

   } catch (MessagingException e) {
    Log.e("catch","error= "+e.getMessage());
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }  

   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   // Dismiss the progress dialog
   if (pDialog.isShowing())
    pDialog.dismiss();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mail Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you include all jar files?

Comment: i dont know about the jar files which i have to include can u name them

Comment: Link here, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

Comment: after adding the mail.jar and activation.jar in lib foldr it is showing error

Comment: 05-25 09:22:13.250: E/AndroidRuntime(950): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
05-25 09:22:13.250: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent(MimeMessage.java:1454)
05-25 09:22:13.250: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.example.mailingdemo.MainActivity$sendMail.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:128)
05-25 09:22:13.250: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at com.example.mailingdemo.MainActivity$sendMail.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)

Comment: add all 3 jars from here and try again, https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add three jar files. 1)additionnal.jar 2)mail.jar 3)activation.jar

You can download from this link .
https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list